# How to Connect Spark SQL with My SQL Database Scala

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**Problem Statement:**

Hi, I am a newbie to the Spark World. I want to query the MySQL Database and then load one table into the Spark. Then I want to apply some filter on the table using SQL Query. Once the result is filtered I want to return the result as JSON. All this we have to do from a standalone Scala base application.

I am struggling to initialize the Spark Context and getting an error. I know I am missing some piece of information.

Can Somebody have a look on the code and tell me what I need to do.

**Code:**

```
import application.ApplicationConstants
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, Dataset, Row, Column, SQLContext}

var sc: SparkContext = null

    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().master("spark://10.62.10.71:7077")
      .config("format","jdbc")
      .config("url","jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test")
      .config("user","root")
      .config("password","")
      .appName("MySQLSparkConnector")
      .getOrCreate()

    var conf = new SparkConf()
    conf.setAppName("MongoSparkConnectorIntro")
      .setMaster("local")
      .set("format", "jdbc")
      .set("url","jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test")
      .set("user","root")
      .set("password","")

    sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val connectionProperties = new java.util.Properties
    connectionProperties.put("user", username)
    connectionProperties.put("password", password)
     val customDF2 = sparkSession.read.jdbc(url,"employee",connectionProperties)

    println("program ended")
```

**Error:**

Following is the error that I am getting:

```
64564 [main] ERROR org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:560)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$5(SparkSession.scala:935)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
    at manager.SparkSQLMySQLDBConnector$.main(SparkSQLMySQLDBConnector.scala:21)
    at manager.SparkSQLMySQLDBConnector.main(SparkSQLMySQLDBConnector.scala)
64566 [main] INFO org.apache.spark.SparkContext - SparkContext already stopped.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:560)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$5(SparkSession.scala:935)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
    at manager.SparkSQLMySQLDBConnector$.main(SparkSQLMySQLDBConnector.scala:21)
    at manager.SparkSQLMySQLDBConnector.main(SparkSQLMySQLDBConnector.scala)
```

P.S: If anybody can give me any link or tutorial that is showing the similar scenario with Scala.

**Versions:**

Spark: 2.4.0
Scala: 2.12.8
MySQL Connector Jar: 8.0.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are messing around creating spark context and configs to connect MYSQL

IF you are using **spark 2.0+** only use SparkSession as a entry-point as

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("Test").getOrCreate

//Add Properties asbelow  
val prop = new java.util.Properties()
prop.put("user", "user")
prop.put("password", "password")
val url = "jdbc:mysql://host:port/dbName"
```

Now read the table with as dataframe

```
val df = spark.read.jdbc(url, "tableName", prop)
```

To access `sparkContext` and `sqlContext` you can access from `SparkSession` as

```
val sc = spark.sparkContext

val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
```

Make sure you have `mysql-connector-java` jar in classpath, Add the dependency to your `pom.xml` or `built.sbt`

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for sharing the code. I have updated the question with the exact versions. Whe I try your stated logic. I am now getting following error on my Spark Console:

Comment: Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() for one-way message.java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.deploy.ApplicationDescription; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 5355123861728677005, local class serialVersionUID = 6543101073799644159

Comment: can you use scala 2.11, I think for scala 2.12 is still experimental.

Comment: can u guide me in another query. If I need to execute a query on the table that I read. I will do it on the DataFrame or in the SQL Context?

Comment: You can both ways, you can do it on dataframe or you can register a table as `df.createOrReplaceTempView("tableName")` and use as `spark.sql("SELECT * From tableName")` or `df.sqlContext.sql("SELECT * From tableName")`

Comment: Hi one quick question, do we also need to add the JDBC connection URL and parameters in the Spark Configuration as well. I am running it on local environment.

Comment: val prop = new java.util.Properties()
    prop.put("user", "root")
    prop.put("password", "")
    val url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
    val df = sparkSession.read.jdbc(url,"employee",prop)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("employee")
    val resultDF = sparkSession.sql("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE id='433'")
    resultDF.count()

Comment: it does not give me any specific count but rather program goes stuck.

Comment: Does the program throws error? can you check `resultDF.show() ` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198238/discussion-between-omer-khalid-and-shankar-koirala).